# Order array object based on specific prop array order

Tags: lodash

```
var values = [
  {
    'props': {
      'name': 'a'
    }
  },
  {
    'props': {
      'name': 'b'
    }
  },
  {
    'props': {
      'name': 'c'
    }
  }
]

var order = ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

How can I reorder `values` based the value of `props.name` being `order`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chaining [indexBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) and [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at), gives you concise and readable code:

```
_(values)
    .indexBy('props.name')
    .at(order)
    .value();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var indexedValues = _.indexBy(values, function(val) { 
    return val.props.name; 
});

/*
indexedValues is equal to:
{ a: { props: { name: 'a' } },
  b: { props: { name: 'b' } },
  c: { props: { name: 'c' } } }
*/

var result = order.map(function(x) { 
    return indexedValues[x]; 
});
```